# C++ custom deleter chaining?

Tags: c++

I have a shared pointer with a custom deleter and want to create another shared pointer from it with a custom deleter that does some work before invoking the original custom deleter.  Something like...

```
std::shared_ptr<X> foo;

{
    std::shared_ptr<X> bar(new X(), Deleter);

    foo.reset(bar, My_Deleter(bar.get_deleter()));
}
```

When bar goes out of scope, nothing should happen because of foo.  When foo goes out of scope, My_Deleter runs and then invokes Deleter.

Is it possible to chain custom deleters like this?  My_Deleter stores a copy of Deleter on construction, but I'm not sure what the type declaration would look like.

Comment: Instead of `std::shared_ptr<X, Deleter> bar = new X();`, do you mean `std::shared_ptr<X> bar { new X(), Deleter{} };`? (`shared_ptr` only has one template parameter; the type of deleter is erased)

Comment: Yes, flubbed the syntax.

Comment: Good replies below.  Thinking what I need to do is have My_Deleter use a member variable to hold a copy of the original shared_ptr with Deleter as its custom deleter, and create a new shared_ptr with My_Deleter as its custom deleter.  For example... foo.reset(bar.get(), My_Deleter(bar)).  When foo goes out of scope, it'll run My_Deleter which can reset its member to run Deleter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the deleter type when calling `shared_ptr::get_deleter()`, so you have to specialize your custom delete class accordingly.

And I'm not sure you can pass a `shared_ptr` object to `reset()` anyway. It expects a new `T*` pointer as input, and `shared_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`, AFAIK.  Only the constructor, `operator=()`, and `swap()` method allow a `shared_ptr` as input to invoke sharing.  The [`reset()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) even warns about this:

> If the object pointed to by ptr is already owned, **the function results in undefined behavior.**

So you would have to use `operator=` or `swap()` to assign `bar` to `foo` so that `bar'`s `X` object gets shared.

Try something like this:

```
template <typename T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T> >
class My_Deleter
{
    Deleter *chained_deleter;

    My_Deleter(std::shared_ptr<T>& p)
        : chained_deleter(std::get_deleter<Deleter>(p));
    {
    }

    void operator()(T *ptr) const
    {
        //...

        if (chained_deleter)
            (*chained_deleter)(ptr);
    }
};
```

```
std::shared_ptr<X> foo;
{
    std::shared_ptr<X> bar(new X, Deleter);
    foo = std::shared_ptr<X>(bar, My_Deleter<X, decltype<Deleter> >(bar));
}
```

Not sure if this would really work, though.  It depends on if/how `shared_ptr` preserves the original deleter when sharing the same object pointer with a different deleter.  I have a feeling that `bar`'s original `Deleter` might get lost when it goes out of scope and not be safely chainable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the deleter for shared_memory can only safely be set on allocation of the memory, that can't be done. Different shared_ptrs can't have different deleters. And in response to doing some work before going out of scope (the reason for the other deleter), if you want to do some extra work before deleting it, then you can just call a separate function that will do the work before the end of the scope. Check some condition for what you might want and do that work before leaving.

Comment: Ok, but since deleters are type erased what would the member of My_Deleter look like that holds the copy to Deleter?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a `std::shared_ptr<T>` object to `reset()`. It expects a new `T*` pointer as input instead, and `shared_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`, right?. Besides, only `shared_ptr`'s constructor and `operator=` allow a `std::shared_ptr` as input to invoke proper sharing. The `reset()` reference you link to even warns about this: "*If the object pointed to by `ptr` is already owned, **the function results in undefined behavior**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right, I accidentally read over that line. If reset is not a safe way to link the point to the object, I'm not sure there's a way to do this. Looking through the documentation, you can only set the deleter on allocation of the memory, meaning you can't have a separate deleter depending on which pointer you have pointing to it. Sorry for that crucial mistake! Updating answer.